# Why is pymongo spawning (so many) waiting connections?

Tags: python, mongodb, networking, pymongo

I use a thin layer of python to connect to a Mongo database. I call the python from C++ and this works fine.

So C++ -> Python -> Mongo and back to Python -> C++

I'm using PyMongo and I'm on Windows Seven.

I want to know if the Mongo database is up and running so I do something like this in Python: (please don't worry about the quirky return variable)

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017, serverSelectionTimeoutMS = 20)
ret=[]
try:
    client.server_info()
    ret.append("up")
    client.close()
except Exception as e:
    ret.append("down")

return ret
```

But this, when the server is UP, invariable spawns a process (process 'hacker' -> network) sitting and waiting until it times out, not after 20 milliseconds but, it seems, 30 seconds. As I check if the database is up, fairly often, I get hundreds of sitting, waiting, processes/connections.

Am I doing something wrong or is PyMongo not working that well on Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Spawns a process, or a thread? How do you know that something is being spawned - is it from the Windows Task Manager monitoring your client program? Or are you seeing something in the mongod log?

Comment: It's open TCP/IP connections (so some form of process I guess) and I see them in Process Hackers -> Network Tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it and as it seems to be no real fix for this problem, and that the problem might / will cause weird problems I thought i'd share my fix:

1: make and use a global connection, don't connect and close, reuse instead.

when checking if database is up or not, first check if there is a global connection

2: if so, use it. If it has been dropped (which should "never" happen, only when say rebooting your server or hardware failure) then the timeout will be long.

3: If it doesn't exist, use my code with the serverSelectionTimeoutMS = 20 which won't spawn another waiting thread/process and also is quick.